# Strange behavior of pure virtual function

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    B();

public:
    virtual void print()=0;
};

void B::print()
{
    cout << "B::print"; 
}

int main()
{ 
   B *bp;
   bp->B::print();  /* Type-A   works fine */
   bp->print();     /* Type-B   segmentation fault */

   return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am trying to invoke pure virtual function via 'bp'.
Now in main function there are two types of call (Type-A, Type-B). My question is why A works but B doesn't. Moreover why compiler allows to invoke a non-static function without creating an object.

Comment: Re: "*why compiler allows to invoke a non-static function without creating an object.*"  Because the compiler assumes you know what you're doing.  There's no simple way for a compiler to check that `bp` points to something valid in the general case.

Comment: Depending on your warning level, you should see something like `warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'bp' used`.

Answer (score 5):

`bp` doesn't point to a valid object so you're experiencing undefined behavior. In this case, `A works but B doesn't` is a perfectly valid undefined behavior. Note that you couldn't make `bp` point to an object of type `B` because it's an abstract type. If you derived another class and implemented `print` then you could point `bp` at that child object.

Answer (score 4):

Both are undefined behavior, and anything can happen. `bp` is not initialized, so calling methods on it or dereferencing it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The point:

1. `bp->B::print()` might work because: `B::print()` is explictly given and  has a valid pointer, and the function itself does not involve with `*this` pointer. It will be translated to `B::print(bp)` and `bp` is neglected.
2. `bp->print()` might not work because the code will look for `vptr` of the object `bp` points to, which does not exist. The `vptr` gives a wrong position to `vtable` and the function call will fail. It is translated into sth. like : `bp->vptr->vtable['print'](bp)' and you can see both`vptr`and`vtable` not defined.